# Pulling secrets from external hashicorp vault to Kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, vault

I cannot pull secrets from external hashicorp vault to kubernetes environment.
I installed hashicorp vault with docker compose. Then I created sa and secret in the Kubernetes environment. and I added kubernetes ca.cert, jwt and ip information to the external vault. Then I created kv and pod yaml, just like in this link. I proceeded from this link, but I could not pull Kubernetes secrets.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-external-vault

this is what i expected

```
kubectl exec devwebapp -- curl -s localhost:8080 ; echo
{"password"=>"salsa", "username"=>"giraffe"}
```

this is what actually happens

```
kubectl exec devwebapp -- curl -s localhost:8080 ; echo
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>

kubectl exec devwebapp -- curl -s 172.23.19.101:30000 ; echo         
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>

kubectl logs devwebapp

2024-03-15 13:36:52 - Exception - The secret request failed: {"errors":[]}
:
        /app/lib/service.rb:43:in `block in <class:ExampleApp>'
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1635:in `call

43 : if vault_response.status != 200
      raise Exception.new "The secret request failed: #{vault_response.body}"
    end
```

-> pod running case

```
cat > devwebapp.yaml <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: devwebapp
  labels:
    app: devwebapp
spec:
  serviceAccountName: internal-app
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: burtlo/devwebapp-ruby:k8s
      env:
      - name: VAULT_ADDR.
        value: "http://172.23.10.51:8200"
      - name: VAULT_TOKEN
        value: "abcd.abc"
EOF
```

Is there anything else I should add? I proceeded from here.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-external-vault